# SSIS 2012 Tries to Check Out Package When Viewing a Script

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, ssis

When trying to view a script component in an SSIS 2012 package I get the error:

> TF10151: Cannot lock item <*item path/name*>.  The item <*item path/name*> is checked out by *Doe, John* in workspace *blahblah*.

My main problem is that I don't want to check the script out, I just want to view it.

Our TFS, ver 2015, is set to NOT enable multiple check outs, for obvious reasons.  This did not seem to be a problem when we were hitting a 2012 TFS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling automatically check out for "Editing" from "VS\Tools\Options\Source Control\Environment\Editing". Set the option to "Do nothing".

[image]